# Lightning Dashboard Filter Limitations

Tags: lightning, reporting, dashboard

I am using Lightning.

I want to display a list of all u.s. states in a dashboard filter so the user can filter the data set by any state they wish. I'm running into a salesforce limit and it appears I can only show 10 options.

Is there an alternative workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Idea was created related to this before and it has been delivered in summer 15. It has been made available on basis of Request raised to Salesforce.

By default, the limit to the amount of options available in a Dashboard Filter is 10. By request, the limit can be increased to a maximum of 50.

Here's how to request a limit increase:-

1. Confirm that your Organization's edition is either Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, or Developer edition.
2. Have your System Administrator create a case with Salesforce Support.
3. In the "General Application Area," field, select Feature Activation.
4. In the case description, please include:

   - Feature requested: Max Number of Dashboard Filter Options
   - Organization ID where you want the limit to be increased (Navigate to Setup | Company Profile | Company Information):
   - Confirm that you are the system admin in charge of making this request.
   - What is your current limit?
   - What is your requested limit?

Reference:-

- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kMtzAAE
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214414&language=en_US&type=1